# Icons in Toolbar control not showing in excel 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a Userform with Toolbar control with icons, its attached to an Imagelist control (MSCOMCTL.OCX).
Everything is working just fine in 32 bit excel.
But in 64 bit excel the icons disappear.
Is there any solution for that?

[image: that is the orginal 32 bit]
[image: that how it looks like in 64 bit]

thank you.

I tried to register mscomctl.ocx to the syswow64 library.

Comment: It looks like the common controls of MsComCtl , such as the Toolbar and ImageList contols, are not compatible with 64-bit version of Excel, as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office) article.

Comment: Yes you right, but what is the alternative, is there any replacment for the listview control?

Comment: Try using the available controls in the Microsoft Forms library to achieve the same sort of thing.  It may require some creativity on your part.  :-)

Comment: Ok thanks what i will probably do.